# I have a 2004 Ford Expedition I lowered the passenger window for fresh air and I could not close it now

Tags: ford, power-windows, expedition

I need to raise window until I get it to a shop or fix myself.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Is it not working with the switch? If not, then try holding the lock button on the remote (5 to 15 seconds necessary) - this can also make it close - usually or possibly standard (iirc) on ford products around then...